# Getting "nothing changed" when commiting in Mercurial to Google Code

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I set up a new project on Google Code and have set Mercurial as my Source Control.

I did an `hg clone <url>` just like the Checkout page states and got a copy of this repository locally.  At the moment, it's still empty.

Now I added some files in this folder and tried committing them with: `hg com -m "Initial Commit"` but I am always getting back `nothing changed`.

So I check the status with `hg status` and get:

```
? file1
? file2
```

So Mercurial knows that these files should be added but I am still getting `nothing changed` when trying to commit.  Obviously this happens when trying to `push` as well but I guess that's because I haven't been able to `commit` yet.

Has anyone encountered this problem ?

Comment: The question mark specifically means an "untracked" file - i.e., one that is not in source control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I was forgetting about `add`.

So now after I cloned, I did a `hg add` and then an `hg com -m "Initial Commit"` and it worked.

Comment: Yeah.  You could have done a `hg commit --addremove -m "initial commit"` to do it all in one command, but it's better as two -- that way you see what's added explicitly before committing.